# Can we check which region is the request coming in for our site on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I wanted to know if it is possible to point where is the request coming from mainly the geographical region.

for example on the architecture which follows:

route53 -> LB -> Ec2.

Is it possible or should we do any architectural changes to find out?

Comment: You have to do it yourself. LB can forward client's IP and based on this you can use third-party services to query its geo location in your app.

Comment: @Marcin any third party service your aware of?

Comment: I don't have any one in particular to recommend. But if you want to stay within AWS, you can consider adding CloudFront to the mix. It can provide you with [geo-location](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/cloudfront-geolocation-headers/) info.

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Did you manage to try CloudFront?

Comment: @Marcin I wanted it for informational purposes only.

Comment: @Marcin can you please look into this query of mine. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811013/how-s3-encryptions-in-transit-with-tls-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to obtain geolocation information using AWS services is through **CloudFront**, which has recently added geolocation headers:

- [Amazon CloudFront adds additional geolocation headers for more granular geotargeting](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/cloudfront-geolocation-headers/)

> The new headers give you more granular control of cache behavior and your origin access to the **viewer’s country name, region, city, postal code, latitude, and longitude, all based on the viewer’s IP address**.

To use this, you would have to added CloudFront distro to your current architecture:

```
Route53 -> CloudFront -> LB -> EC2
```