# How S3 encryptions in transit work. Especially for get and put object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

Use case:

I want to encrypt the data in transit from s3 as well. Encryption at Rest is already present and handled by S3 encryption key.

My Findings:

I found few articles where is it sates modifying the bucket policy with "aws: SecureTransport" condition.

here is sample bucket policy:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
"Effect":
"Principal":
"Action":
"Resource": "arn: aws: s3::: example-bucket/**,
"Condition":
I
"Bool":
{
"aws: SecureTransport":
"false"
```

My concern:

By doing this how the decryption at the receiver end happens? how it needs to be handled?

Assuming a application is accessing the S3 data for some reports.

Could any one help me with this?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-policy-for-config-rule/

Comment: Do you know what TLS is and how it works, what specifically is unclear?

Comment: @luk2302 i get your point now. 
I have modified the question.

Comment: Okay, so you do ***not*** understand what TLS is and how it works!? Please google it and read about it, it ensures data in transit is encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encryption in transit refers to using **HTTPS** protocol to upload your objects to S3. S3 supports both `HTTP` (unencrypted) and `HTTPS` (encrypted) [endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html). Just like with any other website that uses `HTTPS`, you don't have to do anything. All encryption/decryption is done automatically through HTTPS.

However, since S3 supports `HTTP`, it may be a security risk to upload objects through `HTTP`, as objects travel the Internet in a plain-text form. Thus, you can **enforce HTTPS** for your bucket by setting up the following S3 bucket policy:

- [What S3 bucket policy should I use to comply with the AWS Config rule s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-policy-for-config-rule/)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you don't need to do anything with the bucket. Encryption *in transit* depends on the settings of your, well, *in transit* methods. So, when you say *application is accessing the S3 data* - it's not enough. For example, CLI and API encrypt the data out of the box.

If you have a static website, then you can't set it up as HTTPS (that is, with encryption) - only HTTP. (this statement is not 100% correct; but consider it good enough for now). So, if you want to have a static website, then you can front it with CloudFront and have it run over HTTPS.

Comment: sorry, @sumanthshetty - you will need to explain in better English... but my point is that typically you *don't* need to explicitly encrypt anything!